Databricks Runtime Upgrade 9.1 LTS to 14.3 LTS: Handling CAST and Data Type Mismatch Errors
We are trying to do a runtime upgrade from Databricks 9.1 LTS to 14.3 LTS since 9.1 is retiring this September.
However, I am facing below errors in my libraries :

Error :  [CAST_INVALID_INPUT] The value '01/01/1900' of the type "STRING" cannot be cast to "TIMESTAMP" because it is malformed. Correct the value as per the syntax, or change its target type. Use try_cast to tolerate malformed input and return NULL instead. If necessary set "spark.sql.ansi.enabled" to "false" to bypass this error. SQLSTATE: 22018

This error was resolved by setting spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy to legacy at the Cluster Configuration level using Spark config. Setting spark.sql.ansi.enabled to false didn't help since its default value is false as per the documentation.

Error : [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.BINARY_OP_DIFF_TYPES] Cannot resolve "(coalesce(EndDate, '2078/06/01') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR)" due to data type mismatch: the left and right operands of the binary operator have incompatible types ("STRING" and "INTERVAL YEAR"). SQLSTATE: 42K09;

This error persists despite the configuration change and the documentation doesn't mention any other config change to bypass this.
Questions:

Is spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy legacy safe for long-term use in production? The documentation mentions it as a temporary fix. Will Databricks remove support for this setting?

Fixing this via config is preferred because changing the actual code would require modifying 50-60 libraries which is time consuming.

Is there any other configuration to fix the second error?

How can we set spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy legacy at a global level for all-purpose clusters? The documentation mentions this for SQL warehouses.


Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Setting spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy to LEGACY is not recommended for production environments.
When this setting is used, Spark SQL falls back on old CAST operations instead of using the newer ANSI CAST.
This means that any invalid casts during table insertions could result in NULLs or incorrect values being inserted, rather than triggering an exception.

For long-term production use, it is better to set
spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy to ANSI.

Regarding the ERROR:

Error : [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.BINARY_OP_DIFF_TYPES] Cannot resolve
"(coalesce(EndDate, '2078/06/01') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR)" due to data
type mismatch: the left and right operands of the binary operator have
incompatible types ("STRING" and "INTERVAL YEAR"). SQLSTATE: 42K09;

Setting "spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy" to "CORRECTED" will allow implicit casting.
spark.sql("set  spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=CORRECTED")

Results:
DataFrame[key: string, value: string]

As you mentioned that you want the spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy legacy at the Cluster Configuration level using Spark config.
You can followthe below steps:
Step 1:  In the you Cluster page Click on EDIT
Step 2: Go to Advanced Options
Step 3: In the Spark Config use
spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy LEGACY


Step 4: Confirm & Restart The cluster.
Results:
current_policy = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy")
print(f"The current value of spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy is: {current_policy}")

The current value of spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy is: LEGACY

